# How to do the equivalent of a double for loop append for SQL

Tags: sql, dataframe, presto

I'm setting up this table in SQL (Presto, also new to sql) that has 2 columns, `col1` and `col2` These two columns are generated from two other existing tables `table1` and `table2`. To keep things simple, let's say `col1` from `table1` has 3 values and `col2` from `table2` has 2 values. I want the table I want to create to look like this (let's call it `table3`, and I'll use `col1.1` to denote the first value in that col and so on and so forth):

```
col1     |    col 2
--------------------
col1.1   |   col2.1
col1.1   |   col2.2
col1.2   |   col2.1
col1.2   |   col2.2
col1.3   |   col2.1
col1.3   |   col2.2
```

I know how to do this in Python using Pandas like I did here (dummy example):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['sam', 'john']
combined_lst = []
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        combined_lst.append({'col1': i, 'col2': j})
table = pandas.io.json.json_normalize(combined_lst)
print(table)
```

Table output:

```
   col1  col2
0     1   sam
1     1  john
2     2   sam
3     2  john
4     3   sam
5     3  john
```

Basically it should be in the format of that table above. I've looked into trying out `UNION ALL` iteratively but I'm not too sure if I'm on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `cross join`:

```
select row_number() over (order by t1.col1, t2.col2) as id, t1.col1, t2.col2
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2;
```

The `row_number()` is in case the first column is supposed to be part of the data.